# Definite integral of modified bessel function of second kind with order zero

Tags: integration

```
I am solving integral equation by Wiener Hopf method
```

$\int_{0}^{\infty}K_{0}\left(\left|x-\xi\right|\right)u\left(\xi\right)d\xi=-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}$

```
I get solution as
```

$u\left(x\right)=-\frac{e^{-x}}{\pi\sqrt{2\pi x}}$

```
Is there any way I can plug solution into origin equation and verify correctness?
```

Comment: Once you plug $u(\xi)$ back into your equation, you've effectively got a Laplace transform evaluated at some point. So a table of Laplace transforms may be handy here. Alternatively, you can view the LHS as an appropriate convolution and use an appropriate transform to verify its validity.

Comment: @Semiclassical If I use Laplace transform, it's not convolution form.

Comment: Hence my weaselly phrase 'appropriate transform.' The simplest way to go, I suppose, would be to take $f(x)=K_0(|x|)$ and $g(x) = u(x)H(x)$ where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function. Then the above is precisely the convolution of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: @Semiclassical I misunderstand your comment on " Laplace transform evaluated at some point" at first. It's a good way to go. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following Semiclassical's comment, we may first prove that:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{kit}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}\,dt =  K_0(|k|) \tag{1}$$
then that:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-\xi}}{\sqrt{\xi}}\,e^{-\xi i t}\,d\xi = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{1+it}}\tag{2} $$
and the original integral is converted into:
$$ -\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{xit}}{\sqrt{1+t^2}\sqrt{1+it}}\,dt \tag{3}$$
that is not difficult to evaluate through the residue theorem.